# Close WPF user control inside Winform application and free memory

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, user-controls

I have a `UserControl` placed inside a `WinForm`.

I you want to close only the `UserControl`.
So i found that I can  deal with `Visibility`.

```
UserControl.Visibility = Collapsed;
```

or remove the `UserControl` from the `Parent` using :

```
container.Children.Remove(UserControl);
```

But what i need is to remove all `resources` used by this `UserControl` because it cosume a lot of memory.
Is there a way how to close that `UserControl` and clean up memory.

Comment: Can you not do control.Dispose() to clear the resources??

Comment: You can use the Unloaded event. There you will be able to dispose all your resources. Then, you can only change the UserControl or remove it to fire the Unloaded event.